# Why use apply() or call() when you can pass the target object as a parameter?

Tags: javascript, this

I understand the use cases for using apply() and call(). You can essentially call a function from another object, and specify the this binding. This of course, only make sense if said function uses the this keyword.

What I don't understand, is, why would you create a function inside an object, and then decide that you want to reuse it somewhere else by changing this? To me it sounds like the function made sense in the first object, and rather than refactoring the function to live on its own, the programmer decided to just leave it there and call it with apply/call.

It would make more sense to me to take that function out of that object, and put it somewhere else where it's clearly visible that it can be used by different objects, by having it take that target object as an explicit parameter.

Am I missing something?

Comment: So your rather want `String.toUpperCase("aa")` instead of `"aa".toUpperCase()`? That would basically mean you're voting against any instance methods accessing the object they're called on. That would be a huge step backwards imo.

Comment: It doesn't make much sense placing a function on 1 object, and calling that function on another.  But Javascript doesn't stop you doing stuff that doesn't make sense.  If it's something that get's used again & again on lots of objects, then the prototype would be a logical place to put it.

Comment: @connexo I don't think that's what OP is advocating.

Comment: The only real practical application of this I find is something like `Array.prototype.slice.call(arrayLike)`. And that only because the internals of `slice` are known and stable. Using this with custom objects is hardly practical, methinks. I'd call it a weird outgrowth of the somewhat novel approach Javascript takes to objects and its peculiar technique to propagate `this`…

Comment: Note though that explicitly passing `this` is used in a lot of cases with event handlers and libraries like jQuery; but that's not typically reusing methods of other objects. I've met the rare advocate that suggests that `call` and `apply` enable novel prototype-based programming, but personally I don't really "get" that yet or find it particularly good practice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can give you one example where this is useful. Long time ago before ES6, to achieve javascript inheritance was a bit more complicated - there were two types of inheritance. So in order to create one class and inherit it with another class you had to do something like this:

```
function Parent(){
   this.parentParam="parentParam";
};

Parent.prototype.logThisContext = function(){ 
   console.log(this);
};

function Child(){
   Parent.call(this);
};

Child.prototype = Object.create(Parent.prototype);
```

Now if you want to override parent `logThisContext` function, you should write this:

```
Child.prototype.logThisContext = function(){
   // calling base functionality
   Parent.prototype.logThisContext.call(this);
   // add child functionality
   console.log("overriden behavior");
}
```

If you do not call `logThisContext` with `this`, you will log the prototype itself instead of the concrete instance.

You can play with that code removing the calling of `this` and you will see the difference by yourself :)

EDIT: I am not sure if this gives you the answer you want, but `logThisContext` is technically a function inside object as you mentioned in your answer.

Answer (score -2):

So your rather want `String.toUpperCase("aa")` instead of `"aa".toUpperCase()`?

It would basically mean you're voting against any instance methods accessing the object they're called on.

> It would make more sense to me to take that function out of that object, and put it somewhere else where it's clearly visible that it can be used by different objects, by having it take that target object as an explicit parameter.

That would be a huge step backwards imo, and result in a mess of nested function calls:

Instead of e.g.

```
'abcdef'.toUpperCase().split('').join('.')
```

you'd have to do

```
String.join(
  String.split(
    String.toUpperCase('abcdef'),
    ''
  ),
  '-'
);
```

Comment: What OP is talking about is something like `'acdef'.toUpperCase()` vs. `'abcdef'.toUpperCase.call(someOtherRandomObject)`.

Comment: @deceze I don't think that is what OP is talking about, but from what they've given us, it's hard to tell.